# Trying to import in typescript file. (export is not defined)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, compilation, uncaught-reference-error

Full error:
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at  (c:\Users\user\Documents\vsCode\Slider\src\script.js:2:23)
 @ c:\Users\user\Documents\vsCode\Slider\src\script.js:2:23

I have spent around 3 hours searching for anything that might lead me in the right direction. I'm not very skilled in web development. I had this working in pure JavaScript but then decided to try and redo this in TypeScript. I don't know enough about TS to pinpoint the problem.

I have a typescript file where I have this:

```
import nouislider from "./nouislider";

//import * as nouiSlider from "./nouislider"
var dataElements = document.getElementsByClassName('data');

var coll = Array.from(dataElements);
coll.forEach(dataElement => InitializeSlider
  (dataElement));

 function InitializeSlider(data: Element) {}
```

I have a `nouislider.d.ts` file in the same folder. I imagine that it's importing that file.

I then run this task from within vsCode:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "tsc build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npx tsc",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It then spits this out:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
//import * as nouiSlider from "./nouislider"
var dataElements = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
var coll = Array.from(dataElements);
coll.forEach(dataElement => InitializeSlider(dataElement));
function InitializeSlider(data) { }
```

This is my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD1SJ.png)

`Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` is where the error happens. If I don't import `nouislider` then typescript complains that it can't find it.
What am I missing? Is there a different way to import? Should I not be importing? Am I doing the compiling all wrong? HELP!

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to program in Typescript.

`nouislider.d.ts` is only type definition file, it doesn't translate to javascript.
The error says that you didn't export something what you are trying to import.

So, in order to make it work, I suggest to:

- rename nouslider.js to nouslider.ts
- remove nouslider.d.ts (because it is probably not needed)
- and finally call `default export` inside nouslider.ts (this will export the code as module)

Comment: Renaming nouislider.js to nouislider.ts causes the file to have errors. I'm not sure if that is intended.

Comment: Yes, it is intentional. They will be probably just type errors. An app should be compilable. If you add types into existing functions and constants, you should not see these errors.